# Deleting item on list MVC ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Well on this part it is intended to delete the appointed item, But when executed the item that will be deleted is always the top item.

```
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    db = new RobinsonsDBContext();

    var slider = (from s in db.Sliders
                   where s.Id == new Guid(id)
                   select s).First();
    slider.IsDeleted = true;
    db.Entry(slider).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Sliders");
}
```

What is the problem? just a beginner on mvc.

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: `db.Entry(slider).State = EntityState.Modified;` seems unnecessary. The flag will automatically be set after changes.

Comment: I don't understand what you have written regarding what the actual problem is. Does it delete or not? What does it do, what is it meant to do? Are you sure the error is in this code and not the Index? But you prob want to change .First() to .FirstOrDefault() and then check its not null so to make sure you have the correct or even any item from the DB

Answer (score 3):

Use Like

```
Slider oSlider=db.Sliders.Find(id);
db.Sliders.Remove(oSlider);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It will delete your desired item.